# Dynamically hide component upon selecting a country in checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, onepage-checkout

When selecting a specific country (let's assume *The Netherlands*) in the Magento 2 checkout as a shipping country, I want to hide a custom component. I've added this component by creating a `LayoutProcessorPlugin`. So I'd like to add some *JavaScript* to handle the visibility of this custom field when **The Netherlands** are selected in the *Country* dropdown provided by the *Shipping Address* component.

How would one achieve this?

**P.S.**: I haven't added any templates or mixins for this custom field.

**LayoutProcessorPlugin.php:**

```
class LayoutProcessorPlugin {

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject, array  $jsLayout) {

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['custom_field'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
                'options' => [],
                'id' => 'my-custom-field',
                'tooltip' => [
                    'description' => __('My Custom Tooltip'),
                ],
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_field',
            'label' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            'placeholder' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => [],
            'sortOrder' => 120,
            'id' => 'custom_field'
        ];

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

**TLDR; When selecting The Netherlands as my shipping country the custom field should automatically disappear.**

## **Edit 1**

I've tried the suggested implementation of Aaron Allen by doing the following:

**checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="country_id" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Company_MyModule/js/country-component</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**web/js/country-component.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            imports: {
                update: 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.country_id:value'
            }
        },

        update: function (value) {
            // this.visible(value !== 'NL');
            alert(value);
        }
    });
});
```

Which results in the following errors upon loading the checkout (it doesn't load after the errors have been displayed).[image: Error after adding suggested fix]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a custom component by extending `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract`.
`Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom-component.js`:

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract'
], function (Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            imports: {
                update: 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.country_id:value'
            }
        },

        update: function (value) {
            this.visible(value !== 'NL');
        }
    });
});
```

This will result in the `update` function executing every time the value of the selected country changes. The new value is passed as a parameter.

Now use this component in your js layout instead of `abstract`:

```
'component' => 'Vendor_Module/js/custom-component'
```

Comment: Hi Aaron Allen, I would not have come up with something like this. Thanks so much for your response. But, if I create the new file, and add the component to the layout I see it gets loaded and executed. However, the checkout then errors out on me in `region.js`. I've uploaded an explanatory image of the error [here](http://imgur.com/a/Upb9f). What did I do wrong?

Comment: The error indicates that the `country_id` component was not found relative to `region_id` (they should both be children of `shipping-address-fieldset`). Maybe you moved one or the other? I don't understand how adding the component I posted would cause this error. It works without error in my 2.1.6 install.

Comment: The weird thing is that it seems to work on all fields except for the country dropdown. Could it be that it has to do with the fact that it might be not set when the page loads? Or maybe because it's a dropdown instead of a text field?

Comment: Even after adding it into a fresh Magento 2.1.6 installation [it doesn't seem to work](http://imgur.com/a/ckSkh). See the edit in my original question for how I implemented it.

Comment: have you run command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy and remove browser cache.

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya, yes. It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: You're using the component for `country_id` but it should be used for the field that you want to hide when 'NL' is selected. Since you're adding the field in a layout processor, it should go in there.

Comment: Aaron Allen, you are a saint! Thanks. We're basically pretty dumb.

Comment: Above code is for shipping address. How we can hide element on the basis of billing address country id field?

Answer (score 1):

**Vendor_Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Vendor_Module/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function ($, quote) {
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('change',"#shipping-new-address-form [name='country_id']",function(e){
            if(typeof($(this).val()) != "undefined" && $(this).val() !== null) {
                var countryId = $(this).val();
                if(countryId != "GB") {
                    $(".yourclass").hide();
                } else {
                    $(".yourclass").show();
                }
            }
        });
    });
    return function (targetModule) {
        targetModule.crazyPropertyAddedHere = 'yes';
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create js component

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'mage/translate'
], function (AbstractField, $t) {
    'use strict';

    return AbstractField.extend({
        defaults: {
            imports: {
                update: 'checkout.steps.shipping-step.shippingAddress.shipping-address-fieldset.country_id:value'
            },
            modules: {
                vat_id: '${ $.parentName }.vat_id'
            }
        },

        /**
         * Initializes UISelect component.
         *
         * @returns {UISelect} Chainable.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            this.vat_id().visible(false);
            return this;
        },
        update: function (value) {
            if(value == 'GB'){
                this.vat_id().visible(true);
            }else{
                this.vat_id().visible(false);

            }
        }
        
        
            
         
      
    });
});
```