# How to hide payment method based on billing address country ? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, billing-address

Plugin to hide payment method based on billing address country ? Magento 2

Comment: Why plugin ? you can disable specific payment method for specific country from admin

Comment: Will it dynamically,  appear & disappear depending upon the the billing address ?

Comment: it will completely disable specif payment method for that country

Comment: Yes but what if user changes country to the allowed country? Will payment method appear on frontend ?

Comment: Yes,if allowed country is selected payment metod will display...

Comment: Add it as answer , will mark it right.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171861/dynamically-hide-component-upon-selecting-a-country-in-checkout/349181#349181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of plugin/module.

It can be easily managed form Admin configuration:

go to **Stores** > **Configuration** > **Sales** > **Payment Methods**

in most of the payment method you will see option for:

> Payment from Applicable Countries : Change it to `Specific Countries`
>
> Payment from Specific Countries : Exclude country you don't wish to enable payment method.

Comment: Great answer ! i appreciate your help.